# Replacement for obselete OpenDNS Umbrella App on iPhone

Tags: security, iphone-app, content-filtering, web-filtering

I have been a Prosumer OpenDNS Umbrella customer for years, but their iPhone App isn't being upgraded to 64-bit, so it won't work with iOS 11. It provides Umbrella's protections and also allows filtering by category of all internet traffic to/from an iPhone. This has saved me multiple times when I've mistyped web addresses and it reassures me that my child won't as likely stumble across inappropriate content.

Is there another similar product to OpenDNS's prosumer Umbrella for iPhones? I've searched online and keep coming across OpenDNS Umbrella or simple VPNs that don't have the same filtering capabilities or that go overboard (in my opinion) requiring jailbreaking the iPhone so that it can "spy" on all of your users' iPhone activity for you.

Simply blocking adult content in Safari is possible ([as suggested here](http://www.bewebsmart.com/ipod-ipad-iphone/two-ios-7-features-parents-will-love/), go to `Settings->General->Restrictions->Allowed Content->Limit Adult Content`. But that only automatically blocks one category and doesn't necessarily block malicious sites and so many other features I like about OpenDNS Umbrella.

I'm not a company, so I don't think I can use Cisco's other VPN commercial products to do the same thing. And if I could, it would cost a minimum of $380/year for a minimum of 10 users. Prosumer OpenDNS Umbrella has been only $20/year per user who can put it on up to 3 mobile devices.

[cross posted on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306560/replacement-for-opendns-umbrella).

Potentially helpful products (though none seem to be a complete replacement for OpenDNS's Umbrella App):

[Norton SafeConnect](https://dns.norton.com/) (three different sets of DNS servers that are preconfigured to block specific categories. You would have to configure DNS on your phone manually.)

[quad9.net](https://quad9.net) (using DNS server 9.9.9.9) prevents routing to known malicious sites (thanks Patrick Mevzek from Information Security).